# PHP SOAP client doesn't work with a specific WSDL file, with others it works

Tags: php, .net, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to use php SOAP client to use a .net SOAP API, I'm on this problem for a while now.

My simple code is:

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "https://carmellimo.com:8093/JobsWebServ_v1_07/services/JobsWebServImpl?wsdl";
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```

The response is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://carmellimo.com:8093/JobsWebServ_v1_07/services/JobsWebServImpl?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://carmellimo.com:8093/JobsWebServ_v1_07/services/JobsWebServImpl?wsdl" in /home/nircpanel/public_html/api/web/soap-test.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/nircpanel/public_html/api/web/soap-test.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://carmell...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/nircpanel/public_html/api/web/soap-test.php on line 5
```

If I try to add the file_get_contents function:

```
<?php 
    $wsdl = "https://carmellimo.com:8093/JobsWebServ_v1_07/services/JobsWebServImpl?wsdl";
    echo file_get_contents($wsdl);
?>
```

All I get back is a blank page.

I was searching for other http and https WSDL and I found some on google,
I was randomly selected this two:

- https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl
- https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

With these two the code worked perfectly and the functions were available.

I don't know if it helps, but I use the GoDaddy shared hosting (same PHP file location for the three WSDLs).
I was thinking that maybe the problem is at the .NET API side (Or on its server), but when I am using a third party SOAP client or even my browser, it is available, The thoughts that this is the .NET side problem is still on my mind.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDITED:
OK, Suddenly it is working.. No changes were made.. strange!! But I guess it's the computer's second name.

Comment: It seems to me that you simply can not get to the WSDL file for whatever reason: wrong url, access not allowed, etc.

Comment: Hi, tnx.. my assumption is that they didn't block specific my php SOAP client, what do you think they blocked in the .NET server that allow the third party and my browser and block my godaddy php script? any way I can ask for specific changes at the .NET SOAP server if you have any idea.. about the URL, it is correct.. (you can try it yourself using browser if you like:)..